# Basic Ruby/Rails syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am familiar with Java and C and reasonably comfortable with Ruby but get confused by some of the Ruby syntax at times.

For instance what is the following line supposed to be? I assume we are making a function call `protect_from_forgery()`?
But what is the meaning of `with: :exception`? I guess `:exception` is a hash value (e.g `{ :exception => "NullPtr" }` ) but what is `with:`?

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a far bit of syntactic sugar happening in that line. What I think is tripping you up is the shorthand for hashes and symbols. If you're not familiar with symbols, [see here for a good tutorial](http://www.reactive.io/tips/2009/01/11/the-difference-between-ruby-symbols-and-strings/).

With all the syntactic sugar removed, the line could be written as:

```
protect_from_forgery({:with => :exception})
```

Breaking it down, the last argument sent to a method is treated as a hash even without the curly braces. So:

```
protect_from_forgery({:with => :exception})
```

Is the same as:

```
protect_from_forgery(:with => :exception)
```

When a hash's key is a symbol, the hash and key can be defined by putting the colon at the end of the word instead of the beginning. E.g

```
protect_from_forgery(:with => :exception)
```

Is the same as:

```
protect_from_forgery(with: :exception)
```

Lastly, the brackets around the arguments of a method are optional in Ruby. So:

```
protect_from_forgery(with: :exception)
```

Is the same as:

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

Comment: Note that the JavaScript style "symbol as a Hash key" notation only works with *some* symbols. It won't work with symbols like `:$set`, `:@var`, `:'where is pancakes house?'`, ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes `protect_from_forgery` is a methods which takes `optional hast argument` 
[optional hast argument](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/a-better-way-to-set-defaults-in-a-ruby-options-hash)

Here `with:` is a key which is internally  a `method` and `:exception` is value which is also a methods

[see this method protect_from_forgery](https://github.com/rails/docrails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb#L102)